# Why doesn't `stdin.read()` read entire buffer?

Tags: python, json

I've got the following code:

```
def get_input(self):
    """
    Reads command from stdin, returns its JSON form
    """
    json_string = sys.stdin.read()
    print("json string is: "+json_string)
    json_data =json.loads(json_string)
    return json_data

def accept_commands(self):
    while True:
        json_data = self.get_input()
        command = self.command_analyzer.is_command(json_data) # Check wether the command exists. Return it if it does
        #The command exists
        if command is not None:
            #The addon is not currently active
            if analyzer.intent(json_data) not in self.active_addons:
                self.activate_addon(command,json_data)

            #The addon is active and so we need to send the data to the subprocess
            else:
                self.communicate_with_addon(command,json_data,json_string)
```

It reads a json string that was sent to it from another process. The json is read from stdin. 
For some reason I get the following output:

```
json string is: <Some json here>
json string is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Matan/Documents/workspace/ProjectSH/addonmanager/addon_manager.py", line 63, in <module>
    manager.accept_commands()
  File "/Users/Matan/Documents/workspace/ProjectSH/addonmanager/addon_manager.py", line 49, in accept_commands
    json_data = self.get_input()
  File "/Users/Matan/Documents/workspace/ProjectSH/addonmanager/addon_manager.py", line 42, in get_input
    json_data =json.loads(json_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

The json is sent from the following:

```
class MessageReceiver:

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Connect to the AMQP broker and starts listening for messages.
        Creates the a Popen object to pass command info to the addon_manager script (which
        is in charge of managing scripts)
        '''
        addon_manager_path = configuration.addon_manager_path()
        addon_manager_path = os.path.join(addon_manager_path,'addon_manager.py')
        execute = "python " + addon_manager_path
        self.addon_manager = subprocess.Popen(execute, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)


        self.component_name= configuration.get_attribute("name")

        if len(sys.argv)>1:
            host_ip = sys.argv[1]
        else:
            host_ip = 'localhost'

        #Start a connection to the AMQP server
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=host_ip))

        #Create a channel to the server
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        self.channel.queue_declare(queue="kitchen")

        #callback method to be called when data is received
        #It sends the data that is received by the client to the addon_manager
        def data_received(ch, method, properties, body):
            ##TODO: Might want to add some checks. Is body a JSON? etc.
            print("writing data to addon_manager")
            self.addon_manager.communicate(body)


        self.channel.basic_consume(data_received,queue='kitchen',no_ack=True)


        self.channel.start_consuming()
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Your output indicates you called the method twice, and the second time you got an empty response. Where you expecting a second response?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - No. I was expecting only one response (the json string).

Comment: Yet you have two `json string is:` lines. Your method was called twice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I know it was called twice. I was expecting it to block the 2nd time until a new json arrived. I'm surprised by the empty string.

Comment: But your questions states at the end: *the code that writes to this process's stdin writes to it only once*. It won't block a second time because the stream has been closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `stdin.read()` *blocks* until the entire buffer has been read. If all you could decode was one JSON object, then that is all that was sent before `stdin` was closed by the other process.

If you need to stream multiple JSON blocks, you should

a) not close the stream from the writing process, and
b) not do a blocking read in Python.

Read in chunks or lines instead; see  [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-parsing-json-file-in-python/12451465#12451465) and [How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708192/how-do-i-use-the-json-module-to-read-in-one-json-object-at-a-time/21709058#21709058) for techniques for either reading JSON objects that are line-delimited or where multiple lines are used.

You can adapt either to produce a generator function; you'd loop over that to yield one JSON object at a time, blocking in between to wait for the next JSON object:

```
def get_input(self):
    for line in sys.stdin:
        yield json.loads(line)
```

and

```
def accept_commands(self):
    for json_data in self.get_input():
        # do something with `json_data`
```

You are using [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to write to the pipe. This **closes** the pipe after writing to it, after which it waits for the process to terminate.

If you expected the pipe to remain open, don't use `Popen.communicate` and instead write directly to the [`Popen.stdin` pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin).

Comment: Couldn't I read until stdin is empty? Why put the timeout?
Either way: The json itself in the first read attempt is okay (i.e the `json.loads()` method returns a dict). I'm wondering where the extra space came from and how to deal with it

Comment: @Shookie: `stdin` could be empty while you wait for more data.

Comment: I know. As far as I knock `stdin.read` should block if it doesn't have any more data. I was hoping for it to block and continue only when another json was written to its `stdin`

Comment: Is there an equivalent one that blocks?

Comment: @Shookie: Actually, `sys.stdin` **does** block, by default. How is your stdin connected? (See [Does python's sys.stdin.read() block?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4356989))

Comment: It's connected to its parent process via a pipe. It was spawned by `        self.addon_manager = subprocess.Popen(execute, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` and data is written into the pipe using `self.addon_manager.communicate(body)`

Comment: @Shookie: I am confused now; your question edit seems to imply you are expecting just one JSON object. Yet you are looping with `while True` so you are going to end up calling `self.get_input()` again and again.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm expecting many jsons but they're sent at different times. I'm trying to read a json whenever one is sent and handle it but I get the problem stated above.

Comment: @Shookie: when a blanket `sys.stdin.read()` returns you get all data but the stream has been *closed*. You won't get any more data on that stream.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. As far as I know this is just a pipe that I'm reading and as long as I don't close it on either side I should be able to read from it when new data is put into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59929/discussion-between-shookie-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling **get_input** twice and the second there is nothing in the buffer. You should check if there is something before you try to parse JSON:

```
def get_input(self):
    """
    Reads command from stdin, returns its JSON form
    """
    json_string = sys.stdin.read()
    if json_string:
        print("json string is: "+json_string)
        json_data =json.loads(json_string)
        return json_data
    else:
        return None
```