# How can I tell how much to read from nonblocking stdin?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

`msvcrt` has a handy function for this: [`kbhit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit). Unix doesn't :(

---

I have a function `_Getch()` like:

```
def _Getch():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch
    else:
        return sys.stdin.read(1)
```

It gets exactly one keypress.

The problem comes when someone presses:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> sends `\x1b`. That's **1 byte**: the actual escape character.
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd> sends `\x1b[H`. That's **3 bytes**.
- <kbd>F2</kbd> sends `\x1b[OQ`. That's **4 bytes**.
- <kbd>F5</kbd> sends `\x1b[15~`. That's **5 bytes**.

See where this is going? Once ESC has been read, there is no predicting how long the following sequence will be.

Subsequent `_Getch()` calls *will* get these bytes, but the question is of *how many* `_Getch()` calls.

---

I want to define a function like the following, which will read everything waiting in `stdin` til there's nothing left:

```
def _Kbhit():
    y = []
    while msvcrt.kbhit():         # while something is waiting
        y.append(msvcrt.getch())  # get it!
    return y
```

Here's the Unix equivalent that is my aim ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810703/4532996)):

```
def _Kbhit():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    return sys.stdin.read(waiting_buffer_len)  # ?
```

I just don't know how to define `waiting_buffer_len`.

I've searched through all the relevant docs (`tty`, `termios`, `sys.stdin`, `fcntl`, `os`), but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more searching and unintuitively, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357088/4532996):

> Upon looking at the help documentation for sys.stdin.read, I noticed
>   this:
>
> > read(...)
> >
> > read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.
> >
> > If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is
> >     reached. Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what
> >     was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.

The answer is `waiting_buffer_len` can be any length:

```
def _Kbhit():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        chars = sys.stdin.read(10)
    except TypeError:
        chars = ""
    finally:
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl)
        return chars
```

works perfectly.